# Unable to find weak topology T in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, weak-topology

I am self studying topology and I was unable to solve this question.

Wayne Patty's Question 2.4.5.

> Let $U$ be usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $T$ be the weak Topology on $\mathbb{R}$ induced by the family of all bounded real valued continuous functions that map $(\mathbb{R},U)  $ to $(\mathbb{R}, U)$. Describe $T$.

The problem is, how do I know which topology will be smallest? Also $f_{\alpha}$ 's can be constant functions and more functions also like $\sin x$.

Also, what approach should one follow to find smallest topologies which make the all $f_{\alpha}$'s continuous?

Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, it seems to me that any interval $(a,b)$ is in $T$.

This is because you can have a (bounded) function such as:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}-1&x<a\\\text{linear: }\frac{2x-(a+b)}{b-a}&a\le x\le b\\1&x>b\end{cases}$$

and $f^{-1}((-1,1))=(a,b)$. So, as the interval $(-1,1)$ is open in $U$, the interval $(a,b)$ must be open in $T$ if $f$ is to stay continuous as a map $(\mathbb R, T)\to(\mathbb R, U)$.

However, then it follows that every open set in $U$ is also in $T$, i.e. $T=U$.

Comment: "If I understand your question right, it seems to me that any interval (a,b)∈T." You didn't completed your sentence.

Comment: Can you please write a detailed answer?

Comment: Any interval $(a,b)$ *belongs to* $T$. I will edit the text.

Comment: How did you deduced that Which topology will be smallest in this case?

Comment: All those functions are presumed to be continuous, so the topology $U$ is already one that makes them all continuous. Thus, $T\subseteq U$. All I am trying to do here is to prove the opposite inclusion $U\subseteq T$.